# Creating dynamic table with "dropdown multiselect checkbox" (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am populating a dynamic table in my jsp page. I want to have one column as "dropdown multiselect checkbox" . To create "dropdown multiselect checkbox" i am using (jquery+bootstrap).But only first row is getting created with multiselectCheckbox, other rows are coming as normal select option.

Here is the code :-

```
<html><head>
<script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
    type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#myselect").multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<Table name="test" border="1">
            <TR bgcolor="#33FFFF">
                <td>ManagementIPAddress</td>
                <td>Application name</td>
            </TR>
            <c:forEach var="resultMap" items="${requestScope.snmpGetResultsMap}">
                <TR>
                    <TD><c:out value="${resultMap.key}" /></TD>
                    <TD><select id="myselect" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="checkbox-1">checkbox-1</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-2">checkbox-2</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-3">checkbox-3</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-4">checkbox-4</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-5">checkbox-5</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-6">checkbox-6</option>
                    </select><br />
                    <br /></TD>
                </TR>
            </c:forEach>
        </Table>
</body></head></html>
```

I know its happening because select id should be unique for each row , but now sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Use a common class. Add a class to your select then you can use class selector

Comment: thanks Satpal for suggestion but i am not sure how to make a call to jquery function in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common class. Add a class to your select then you can use [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

HTML:

```
<select class="mySelectClass" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="checkbox-1">checkbox-1</option>
        <option value="checkbox-2">checkbox-2</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mySelectClass").multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<html><head>
<script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
    type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".yourClass").each(function(){
$(this).multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
});
});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<Table name="test" border="1">
            <TR bgcolor="#33FFFF">
                <td>ManagementIPAddress</td>
                <td>Application name</td>
            </TR>
            <c:forEach var="resultMap" items="${requestScope.snmpGetResultsMap}">
                <TR>
                    <TD><c:out value="${resultMap.key}" /></TD>
                    <TD><select class="yourClass" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="checkbox-1">checkbox-1</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-2">checkbox-2</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-3">checkbox-3</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-4">checkbox-4</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-5">checkbox-5</option>
                            <option value="checkbox-6">checkbox-6</option>
                    </select><br />
                    <br /></TD>
                </TR>
            </c:forEach>
        </Table>
</body></head></html>
```

Comment: just replace with yourclass with any css class name you like